# MailKit no se conecta al Gmail en Godaddy Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net

desarrolle una app en Asp .Net mvc y en ella utilizo MailKit para obtener emails. La llamada al método que realiza la conexión lo hago desde Global.asax ya que tengo una funcion que se se conecta cada cierto tiempo y captura los emails. La app en local me funciona bien pero cuando la publico en godaddy no me funciona la conexion al email. 
Saben por que pueda pasar esto, será porque la pagina aun no tiene certificado SSL?

Comment: Qué error ves que te hace pensar que no funciona la conexión?

Comment: yo tengo debajo de la linea de conexion una variable buleana que guardo en bd y me indica si se establece conexion y en el catch la pongo en false. Cuando miro la bd me la establece a false por lo que pienso que esta generando una excepcion

Comment: Significa que puedes ampliar la información en tu pregunta incluyendo el código que usas y el mensaje de error completo en vez de contarnos. :)